# Selenium can't find input element for site... selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element

Tags: python, exception, selenium-webdriver, input, selenium-chromedriver

Can't find element for login input. I'm using selenium and chromedrive in python.
I´ve tried using the xpath for the element as you can see in the following code. The link for the site is also in the code.
Please help

Code:

````
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_experimental_option('detach', True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\...path...\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("http://190.232.89.110/#login")
driver.maximize_window()
time.sleep(10)

bot_report = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody[4]/tr/td[2]/input')```

Terminal:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody[4]/tr/td[2]/input"}
  (Session info: chrome=111.0.5563.65)
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
        (No symbol) [0x0067DCE3]
        (No symbol) [0x006139D1]
        (No symbol) [0x00524DA8]
        (No symbol) [0x0055019F]
        (No symbol) [0x005503AB]
        (No symbol) [0x0057EE62]
        BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76387D69+25]
        RtlInitializeExceptionChain [0x77CDB74B+107]
        RtlClearBits [0x77CDB6CF+191]

---------------------------------------------------------------
Element HTML:
<input id="login-inputEl" type="text" size="1" name="login-inputEl" style="width:100%;" class="x-form-field x-form-text" autocomplete="off" aria-invalid="false" data-errorqtip="">
````

Comment: Please share the HTML in the text format.

Comment: Are you sure that element actually exists?

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
bot_report = driver.find_element(by=By.XPATH,value='/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[1]/table/tbody[4]/tr/td[2]/input')
```

With:

```
bot_report= driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//button[text()="Some text"]')
```

Comment: Hello Harry! I tried your suggestion and it shows the same error message

Comment: This is how it’s done with selenium. You can get the element by ID, className or TagName, if you are having issue with using Pathname. Most times elements might not be visible, so you can sleep for 1 or 2 seconds giving selenium time to wait for the element to be visible